# How to create vuetify toolbar link dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, material-design, vuetify.js

Go to https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/toolbars

On the top left toolbar we see links: store, support, ecosystem, version, locate

How do I create this style of toolbar button link (with dropdown items)?

(I am unable to find an example)

Comment: You can see the layout of vue docs in github. For example drop down for [ecosystem](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/5660b38fd503850c4703e8a09c02a3b659b76ff8/packages/docs/src/components/core/Ecosystems.vue) or [support](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/5660b38fd503850c4703e8a09c02a3b659b76ff8/packages/docs/src/components/core/Supports.vue). Main layout page is [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/5660b38fd503850c4703e8a09c02a3b659b76ff8/packages/docs/src/components/core/Toolbar.vue).

Comment: If you see `<core-*>` component, look for it [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/5660b38fd503850c4703e8a09c02a3b659b76ff8/packages/docs/src/components/core)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a simple plain [menu](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/menus#menu) component.
Click on the example button (dropdown) and on "support"
and you will see, that they behave the same.
If you inspect the "support" button with your browser ([Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Open_the_Inspector), [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) Shortcut F12 for both),
you can see thats a "v-menu"(menu component) and you can see the CSS used for it.

Comment: I tried to add v-menu, but it looks and behaves differently? the menu highlight when mouse over and menu display when clicked.

Answer (score 3):

```
<template>
<div>
        <v-toolbar rounded tile>
        <v-app-bar-nav-icon> </v-app-bar-nav-icon>
        <v-app-bar-title>
            <route-link to="/" tag style="cursor:pointer">ProjectName</route-link>
        </v-app-bar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-items>
            <v-btn flat to="/">
                Home
            </v-btn>
            <v-menu :rounded="rounded" open-on-hover offset-y transition="slide-x-transition" bottom right>
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                    <v-btn flat v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                        Services
                    </v-btn>
                </template>
                <v-list dense>
                    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in services" :key="index" router :to="item.link">
                       <v-list-item-action>
                            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
                        </v-list-item-action>
                    </v-list-item>
                </v-list>
            </v-menu>
            <v-btn to="/about" flat>
                About Us
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn to="/contact" flat>
                Contact Us
            </v-btn>
        </v-toolbar-items>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-toolbar-items class="hidden-sm-and-down">
            <v-btn to="/signup" flat>Sign Up </v-btn>
            <v-btn to="/login" flat>login</v-btn>
        </v-toolbar-items>
        <v-menu open-on-hover transition="slide-x-transition" bottom right offset-y>
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                    <v-icon>mdi-dots-vertical</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="300" tile>
                <v-list dense>
                    <v-subheader>THEMES</v-subheader>
                    <v-list-item-group v-model="theme" color="primary">
                        <v-list-item v-for="(item, i) in themes" :key="i" router :to="item.link">
                            <v-list-item-action>
                                <v-icon v-text="item.icon"></v-icon>
                            </v-list-item-action>
                            <v-list-item-action>
                                <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
                            </v-list-item-action>
                        </v-list-item>
                    </v-list-item-group>
                </v-list>
            </v-card>
        </v-menu>
    </v-toolbar>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data: () => ({
        activate: true,
        theme: 1,
        themes: [{
                text: "Dark",
                icon: "mdi-clock"
            },
            {
                text: "Light",
                icon: "mdi-account"
            }
        ],
        mini: true,
        services: [{
                icon: "mdi-domain",
                title: "Media Monitoring",
                link: "/mmrservices"
            },
            {
                icon: "mdi-message-text",
                title: "Audience Measurement",
                link: "/amrservices"
            },
            {
                icon: "mdi-flag",
                title: "Integration Analysis"
            }
        ]
    })
};
</script>
```